# Drupal 8: Error while attempting to read POST data: 400

Tags: drupal

I get "connection was reset" error every single time I try and place a block in Drupal 8.

Apache error:

Error while attempting to read POST data: 400, referer: http://website/admin/structure/block

Comment: Can you look at your error logs?

Comment: This is the full error from error.log in the "logs" dir of Apache: [Tue Apr 18 14:20:39.152512 2017] [php7:error] [pid 1256:tid 1616] [client IPADDRESS:23442] Error while attempting to read POST data: 400, referer: http://website/admin/structure/block